# null pointer Exception when i downlaod image and store to Sd card in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout linearMain;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    ImageView imageview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        new myAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public ProgressDialog dialog;

        myAsyncTask() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading image...");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        // AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
        // aq.id(recciverimage).image(bitmap);
        // ;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL("http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/"
                        + "1" + ".jpg");
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                try {
                    // The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly,
                    // or
                    // more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    File storagePath = Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                            storagePath, "1.jpg"));
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0,
                                buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        output.close();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            dialog.dismiss();
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/LociiImages/" + "1" + ".jpg";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

            AQuery aq = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
            aq.id(imageview).image(bitmap);

            // recciverimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

    }
}
```

This my code from which i am downloading image from server and store in sd card and from that sd card we print the image on image view http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/1.jpg  using this URl am downloading image to server but unable to store please suggest me where am doing wrong it give Null Pointer Exception .

Comment: where is your logcat??

Comment: when i debug then catchblock Excute

Comment: @MDpatel Please check i am unable to download image to sd card from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Problem is here:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                        storagePath, "1.jpg"));
```

where your `storagePath` is:

```
File storagePath = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

and later you try to Access the downloaded Image in:

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + "/LociiImages/" + "1" + ".jpg";
```

If you compare the storagePath and the path you are looking for, then you will see that you are searching in the sub-Folder `LociiImages` but you didn't save your Picture there.

That's why this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

throws a NPE. Just a Suggestion. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Departure there is no way around. Post your complete Logcat into the bottom of the question!

Comment: no Error is coming no locat http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/1.jpg i just want to download this image and store in sd card